# Getting Error when I try to run my code with pyautogui click function

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

I'm a python beginner, and I was making a small script/macro that executes a specific command when I press q. In this case it should just press 2 double clicks and press 1, but for some reason, when I added the `pyautogui.click(clicks=2, intervals=0.25)`function it broke my code

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard

def action():
        pyautogui.press("2")
        pyautogui.click(clicks=2, intervals=0.25)
        pyautogui.press("1")

def on_press(key):
    try:
        if key.char == "q":
            action()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

def Stop_listner(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

# Collect keyboard inputs
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=Stop_listner) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/sanch/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/ThrowAwayProjects/ideas.py
Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 211, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 284, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 127, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\sanch\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ThrowAwayProjects\ideas.py", line 13, in on_press
    action()
  File "C:\Users\sanch\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ThrowAwayProjects\ideas.py", line 7, in action
    pyautogui.click(clicks=2, intervals=0.25)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 586, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: click() got an unexpected keyword argument 'intervals'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanch\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ThrowAwayProjects\ideas.py", line 23, in <module>
    listener.join()
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 259, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 718, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 211, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 284, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 127, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\sanch\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ThrowAwayProjects\ideas.py", line 13, in on_press
    action()
  File "C:\Users\sanch\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ThrowAwayProjects\ideas.py", line 7, in action
    pyautogui.click(clicks=2, intervals=0.25)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 586, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: click() got an unexpected keyword argument 'intervals'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please add error details

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `pyautogui.click()` doesn't like `intervals=0.25`.  Try:

```
pyautogui.click(clicks=2, interval=0.25)
```

Change the "intervals" option to "interval"